# Hover effect for image with text on top

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a headline ad text on top which should only be visible when hovering over the image. The headline as well as the image contain a link, but I can't get the link to work for my image: when hovering over the headline, the link works, but when hovering over the image, nothing is linked. I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/drenina/ycwmeb09/11/) fiddle.

```
  <article> 
<div class="entry-wrapper">
<header class="entry-header" >
            <div class="entry-meta"><span>Text</span><h2><a  href="https://www.google.com/" >Headline</a></h2>
            </header>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="entry-thumbnail">
    <img width="300" height="300" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597589827317-4c6d6e0a90bd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2080&q=80" alt="" decoding="async"></a>         
    
    <div class="entry-content entry-excerpt">
                </div>

        </div>

</article>

html *, html ::after, html ::before{
box-sizing:border-box}
```

.entry-wrapper{
overflow:hidden;
height:100%
}

```
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header{

opacity:0;
position:absolute;
z-index:15;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:30px;
color:white !important
}
article .entry-wrapper:hover .entry-header{
opacity:1;
transition:.3s ease-in-out;
background-color:#6C836F;
}
article .entry-wrapper{
position:relative
}
article .entry-thumbnail:hover{
opacity:1
}
```

.entry-small .entry-header, .home .entry-thumbnail {
margin:0
}
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header a{
color:white !important
}
article{
width:300px;
height:300px
}
.entry-thumbnail{
display:block
}

```
<article> 
<div class="entry-wrapper">
<header class="entry-header" >
            <div class="entry-meta"><span>Text</span><h2><a href="https://www.google.com/" >Headline</a></h2>
            </header>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="entry-thumbnail">
    <img width="300" height="300" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597589827317-4c6d6e0a90bd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2080&q=80" alt="" decoding="async"></a>         
    
    <div class="entry-content entry-excerpt">
                </div>

        </div>
</article>

html *, html ::after, html ::before{
box-sizing:border-box}
```

.entry-wrapper{
overflow:hidden;
height:100%
}

```
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header{

opacity:0;
position:absolute;
z-index:15;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:30px;
color:white !important
}
article .entry-wrapper:hover .entry-header{
opacity:1;
transition:.3s ease-in-out;
background-color:#6C836F;
}
article .entry-wrapper{
position:relative
}
article .entry-thumbnail:hover{
opacity:1
}
```

.entry-small .entry-header, .home .entry-thumbnail {
margin:0
}
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header a{
color:white !important
}
article{
width:300px;
height:300px
}
.entry-thumbnail{
display:block
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you need @Kt7789:

[click this to see the entire code](https://jsfiddle.net/M_R_CipheredC_E_M_T_/j8sd7930/1/)

```
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: @kt7789 here is another one tell me if it worked.

Comment: I added the css on the site, but please have a look, it is not working correctly...

Comment: are you sure? cause it works perfectly for me.

Comment: [take a look at this](https://pasteboard.co/PU3wUC2EFekT.png) you have a syntax error in your code unclosed `div` tag. maybe this is interrupting with your CSS style .

Comment: no, I did not use the code in my fiddle. Please look at the website link I shared, that is where I added your css. https://kkaajj.s1-tastewp.com/  That is the site.

Comment: Oh, i found out why your style is not working well, look at the images: [the code that you gave from the website](https://pasteboard.co/mgQWn2Jr3y79.png) --- [the one you gave in the question.](https://pasteboard.co/wFoQD1XLzLnM.png).   
you see it's your HTML that mixes up the CSS style. in the question `h2` is inside the `.entry-meta` but in the site `h2` is outside the `.entry-meta` you have been confused when giving the styles. the one i gave you is for your question only, but if you want to use it in another form of HTML you have to pay attention.

Comment: I am sorry I did not provide the correct html as it is on the site. Could yyou help me get it to work on the site? I have tried everything I could think of, but I am failry new to css and html...

Comment: sure i do any thing i can to help you! but you have to wait a title.

Comment: @Kt7789 look at this [image](https://pasteboard.co/ktOb3O3aZ3sK.jpg), is this what you want?

Comment: ok standby i will edit the answer that we're commenting, to what you need.

Comment: Any time friend.

Answer (score 0):

well the problem is that your `heading` title comes over your `image` that's why you can't click on the image or sense the link, it's very easy to solve it, since both `heading` and `image` have the same hyper link you should give them an `a` tag parent:

```css
html *, html ::after, html ::before{
  box-sizing:border-box}


.entry-wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%
  }
  
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header{

  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:15;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:30px;
  color:white !important
  }
article .entry-wrapper:hover .entry-header{
  opacity:1;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color:#6C836F;
  }
article .entry-wrapper{
  position:relative
  }
article .entry-thumbnail:hover{
  opacity:1
  }
.entry-small .entry-header, .home .entry-thumbnail {
  margin:0
  } 
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header a{
  color:white !important
  }
  article{
    width:300px;
    height:300px
  }
  .entry-thumbnail{display:block}
```

```html
<article> 
    <div class="entry-wrapper">
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="entry-thumbnail">
          <header class="entry-header" >
            <div class="entry-meta"><span>Text</span><h2>Headline</h2></div>
          </header>
          <img width="300" height="300" src="" alt="" decoding="async"> 
        </a>
        <div class="entry-content entry-excerpt"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

if you can't change the HTML use JavaScript or j-Query instead:

```js
$(".entry-header").on("click",function(){
  window.location.href = $(".entry-thumbnail").attr("href")
})
```

```css
html *, html ::after, html ::before{
  box-sizing:border-box}


.entry-wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%
  }
  
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header{

  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:15;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:30px;
  color:white !important;
  cursor: pointer;/*added*/
  }
article .entry-wrapper:hover .entry-header{
  opacity:1;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color:#6C836F;
  }
article .entry-wrapper{
  position:relative
  }
article .entry-thumbnail:hover{
  opacity:1
  }
.entry-small .entry-header, .home .entry-thumbnail {
  margin:0
  } 
article .entry-wrapper .entry-header a{
  color:white !important
  }
  article{
    width:300px;
    height:300px
  }
  .entry-thumbnail{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article> 
    <div class="entry-wrapper">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <div class="entry-meta"><span>Text</span><h2><a href="https://www.google.com/">Headline</a></h2></div>
        </header>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="entry-thumbnail">
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597589827317-4c6d6e0a90bd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2080&q=80" alt="" decoding="async">
        </a>
        <div class="entry-content entry-excerpt"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

i gave `cursor: pointer;` to `.entry-header`
i think this will solve it!

Comment: unfortunately I cannot edit the html as it comes from a theme.

Comment: friend, i have given another solution too.
with j-Query.

Comment: I would strongly prefer not to use js or jquery...could you please have a look at the blog here https://kkaajj.s1-tastewp.com/ if it is possible to change it just with css?

Comment: ok i try to give you some examples with css

Answer (score -1):

How about you try modifying the CSS and keeping HTML as it is:

```css
html *,
html ::after,
html ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.entry-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

article .entry-wrapper .entry-header {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    color: white !important;
}

article .entry-wrapper:hover .entry-header {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #6C836F;
}

article .entry-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

article .entry-thumbnail:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.entry-small .entry-header,
.home .entry-thumbnail {
    margin: 0;
}

article .entry-wrapper .entry-header a {
    color: white !important;
}

article {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.entry-thumbnail {
    display: block;
}

article .entry-wrapper a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<article> 
    <div class="entry-wrapper">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <div class="entry-meta"><span>Text</span><h2><a href="https://www.google.com/">Headline</a></h2></div>
        </header>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="entry-thumbnail">
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597589827317-4c6d6e0a90bd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2080&q=80" alt="" decoding="async">
        </a>
        <div class="entry-content entry-excerpt"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: it does not work on my site, Please see this link https://kkaajj.s1-tastewp.com/. I only added the width and height for the article for demonstration purposes, but when I take them out, nothing is diplayed any longer...

Comment: Make sure to remove any conflicting CSS rules that might interfere to cause this issue.

Comment: can you tell me which? I tried everything I could think of...please check the link with the site I provided...